# CAShapeLayer: different line cap at start/end

Tags: ios, cashapelayer

I'm using CAShapeLayer to draw a semicircle and I want to have a kCGLineCapRound at the start and a kCGLineCapButt at the end. How can I do that?

```
UIBezierPath *circlePathMax = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:CGPointMake(self.view.center.x, self.view.center.y) radius:radius startAngle:angle1 endAngle:angle2 clockwise:YES];
             CAShapeLayer *circleMax;
             circleMax               = [CAShapeLayer layer];
             circleMax.path          = circlePathMax.CGPath;
             circleMax.lineCap       = kCALineCapRound;
             circleMax.fillColor     = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
             circleMax.lineWidth     = 10;
             circleMax.strokeColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:255.0/255.0f green:255.0f/255.0f blue:255.0f/255.0f alpha:0.7f].CGColor;
             circleMax.zPosition     = 3;
             [self.view.layer addSublayer:circleMax];
```

I can specify only one generic lineCap

Comment: I'm sorry but it doesn't seems possible.<br>
The workaround could be overlap partially 2 different lines with different cap.

Comment: @Andrea I already tried that but I can't have an overlap because I'm using a color with alpha as strokeColor...

Comment: did you found any easy workaround? @Heisenberg

Comment: @dip unfortunately no. In my case I had to draw a semicircle with transparency on top of an image of a gradient semicircle. This allowed me to use .butt with the background color (with alpha component) as strokeColor to "hide" the squared corners. But it was a specific case.

Comment: Is it possible to share snippet ? @Heisenberg

Answer (score 1):

You could use lineCap `.butt`, and at the end of your `semicircle`, draw yourself a circle.

Answer (score 0):

This is the trick I used. In my case I had to draw a semicircle with transparency on top of an imageView of a gradient semicircle. This allowed me to use .butt with the background color (with alpha component) as strokeColor to "hide" the squared corners.

```
let circleMin = CAShapeLayer.init()
let circlePathMin = UIBezierPath.init(arcCenter: myCenter, radius: myRadius, startAngle: startingAngle, endAngle: endingAngle, clockwise: true)
circleMin.path = circlePathMin.cgPath
circleMin.lineCap = .butt
circleMin.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
circleMin.lineWidth = 14
circleMin.strokeColor = self.containerView.backgroundColor?.withAlphaComponent(0.7).cgColor
circleMin.zPosition = 3
containerView.layer.addSublayer(circleMin)
```